# "He is cuter back then."

Tags: grammar

He is 7 years old.
He found his 1 year old photo and made an expression exactly like it was there.

> **"He is cuter back then."**

What I wanted to say is that his expression when he was a year old looks cuter than his expression now.
Is “**back then**” used correctly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you used "**back then**" absolutely correctly. However, the tense, with respect to grammar, should be the Past tense.

- He was cuter back then.

Sinse he isn't any cuter now than he was in the past.